# Best Data Structure/file to store Matrix to read in Ruby on Rails? jSon? Yaml? Xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, data-structures

I am choosing an optimal data file/source/database to store a matrix, originally from spreadsheet. The current spreadsheet matrix looks like below:

```
    A1 A2 A3 A4
B1  1  2  3  4
B2  3  2  3  4
B3  2  3  1  3
```

My objective is to easily retrieve data from the matrix. The column and row headings act as pointer to the actual data in the matrix.

I am considering json, yaml...but it is so much work to produce hashes with two pointers to every number in the matrix..

Any suggestions?

Comment: how big is the data? how many cols and rows?

Comment: why not just store as a serialized hash, row by row ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The data is probably about 100 * 100

Comment: Row by row hash is not very practical because every row and col points to a unique number. In fact each row/col heading is a range of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to store it and do nothing else about it, I would even go as far as use CSV saved inside a text field, nothing is as simple as that. If you do need to perform certain operations with the matrix, I would suggest trying to use something like postgres hstore: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html and trying to build data representation based on that.

Comment: isn't postgress::hstore doing the same as rails with serialized hash ?

Comment: It is faster in working with hashes and gives you the ability to make pure-SQL combined queries with all their functionality: sum, average, array conversion and so on. Everything depends on what you plan to do with your matrixes afterwards.